# Can't locate Email/Sender/Simple.pm on OS X Mavericks

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am running perl using CGI on OS X Mavericks.

When I run the perl script it throws following error

> Can't locate Email/Sender/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ../shared ../shared /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16

When I try to install Email sender module using cpan

```
cpan> install Email::Sender::Simple
```

It says

> Email::Sender::Simple is up to date (1.300016).

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is the module installed? What is in `@INC`? (the rest of the error message should tell you.) Does the user your webserver runs as have permission to access all of the directories in the path to the module, as well as read permissions on the module itself?

Comment: Here is inc path INC contains: ../shared ../shared /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16

Comment: Okay, and where is `Email/Sender/Simple.pm`? (Please [edit] these details into your question instead of leaving them in comments, which are difficult to read.)

Comment: Here is the module path
 R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Sender-1.300016.tar.gz
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/Email/Sender/Simple.pm
    Installed: 1.300016
    CPAN:      1.300016  up to date
    Ricardo SIGNES (RJBS)
So perl is unable to find this as @INC does not contain /opt. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `cpan` from one install of Perl, and you're running your script using another. Instead of `cpan Email::Sender::Simple`, execute the following

```
perl -MCPAN -e'shell'
```

then

```
install Email::Sender::Simple
```

and

```
quit
```

Ensure that the same `perl` is used as the one that is used to run your script by providing the full path to `perl` if necessary.